# Using a BFS for a Maze?

Tags: java

I have been trying to solve this question http://dwite.ca/questions/haunted_house.html with a Breadth First Search, but I can't get all the testcases correct, and I think the problem is that, it will only count the direct shortest path to the end, and it will count any candies open, but it will not count the shortest path through the candies here is the code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class HalloweenCandy {

    static int n, candy;
    static int minsteps, maxcandy;
    static int totCandies=0;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Desktop\\Java\\HalloweenCandy\\src\\halloweencandy\\DATA5.txt"));

        while (s.hasNext()) {
            n=Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine().trim());
            char[][]maze=new char[n][n];
            int xStart =0;
            int yStart =0;

            for(int y=0;y<n;++y){
                String text = s.nextLine().trim();
                for(int x=0;x<n;++x){

                    maze[x][y]=text.charAt(x);
                    if(maze[x][y]=='B'){
                        xStart=x;
                        yStart=y;
                    }
                }
            }
            candy=0;
            minsteps=0;
            BFS(maze,xStart,yStart);
            System.out.println(candy+" "+minsteps);
        }
    }
    public static void BFS(char[][]maze,int xStart,int yStart){
        Queue<int[]>queue=new LinkedList<int[]>();
        int start[]={xStart,yStart,0,0};
        queue.add(start);

        while(queue.peek()!=null){
            int[]array=queue.poll();
            int x=array[0];int y=array[1];

            if(x<0||y<0||y>n-1||x>n-1)continue;
            if(maze[x][y]=='#')continue;
            if(maze[x][y]=='*'){                 
                candy++;               
                minsteps=array[2];
                maze[x][y]='.';
            }
            if(maze[x][y]>='a'&&maze[x][y]<='f'){
                if(candy <maze[x][y]-'a'+1)continue;
            }
            int[][]points = {{0,1},{1,0},{-1,0},{0,-1}};
            for(int i=0;i<4;++i){
                int sta[]={x+points[i][0],y+points[i][1],array[2]+1};
                queue.add(sta);
            }
           maze[x][y]='#';
        }

    }
}
```

and here are the test cases 
http://dwite.ca/home/testcase/232.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the write track, but you missed something important.

```
    while(queue.peek()!=null){
        int[]array=queue.poll();
        int x=array[0];int y=array[1];

        if(x<0||y<0||y>n-1||x>n-1)continue;
        if(maze[x][y]=='#')continue;
        if(maze[x][y]=='*'){                 
            candy++;               
            minsteps=array[2];
            maze[x][y]='.';
        }
        if(maze[x][y]>='a'&&maze[x][y]<='f'){
            if(candy <maze[x][y]-'a'+1)continue;
        }
        int[][]points = {{0,1},{1,0},{-1,0},{0,-1}};
        for(int i=0;i<4;++i){
            int sta[]={x+points[i][0],y+points[i][1],array[2]+1};
            queue.add(sta);
        }
       maze[x][y]='#'; // <== this part is wrong
    }
```

What you're doing in that last assignment is making every square you step on into a wall. This would be the right approach if you could get through the maze without backtracking, but that's not the case. Instead, what you want to do is make sure you don't backtrack until you've picked up a new piece of candy. So, try something like this instead:

```
maze[x][y]='a'+candy;
```

That way, once you pick up a new piece of candy the square will be usable again.

However, there's still an issue here. Think about how BFS would work on this map:

```
3
...
*B*
...
```

If [0,0] is the top-left tile, then your BFS algorithm will visit the tiles in this order: [1,2], [2,1], [0,1], [1,0]. What's wrong with that? Billy is jumping between all of his neighboring squares! What you actually want him to do is restart the BFS each time he gets a new piece of candy. I'll leave it to you to figure out how to do that part.

***Edit***

Here's the basic algorithm you want to follow:

1. Begin at the `start` position.
2. Use BFS to search for the nearest piece of candy. The first piece of candy found with BFS is the nearest (or tied for nearest)!
3. After finding a piece of candy, you need to find the *next* closest piece to your *current position*, so treat your current position as the new `start` for another BFS.

Comment: So kind of a greedy approach?or do you mean continuing the bfs loop when you get to a candy?

Comment: Something like [Star,Dot, B, Star, Star, Star] would not work, by the way I couldn't use asterisks and dots because it blocked some of it. because then the optimal solution would be to start at the leftmost star

Comment: You're right. In that case, it's more complicated because you have to explore all permutations of candy-grabbing order and return the one that results in the minimum number of steps. You should actually be able to do this using [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) since the permutations would have repeated sub-problems.

Comment: @Panphobia - BTW, you can [use backticks](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) to type "code", e.g.: `*.B***`

Comment: I am not really sure on dynamic programming anyway, yes I know the fibonacci dynamic programming simplification, and some others but I really do not know what the meaning of dynamic programming is, even with wikipedia, I think I have solved other problems using it but I just don't know the informal and formal definitions are. All I see is using arrays to store something that a recursive function would have to generate again and again.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished solving it your way, the "greedy" way here is the code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class HalloweenCandy {

static int n, candy;
static int minsteps, maxcandy;
static int totCandies = 0;
static boolean[][] is;

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Desktop\\Java\\HalloweenCandy\\src\\halloweencandy\\DATA5.txt"));
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        n = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine().trim());
        char[][] maze = new char[n][n];
        is = new boolean[n][n];
        int xStart = 0;
        int yStart = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < n; ++y) {
            String text = s.nextLine().trim();
            for (int x = 0; x < n; ++x) {

                maze[x][y] = text.charAt(x);
                if (maze[x][y] == 'B') {
                    xStart = x;
                    yStart = y;
                }
            }
        }
        candy = 0;
        int tot = 0;
        int y = 0, x = 0;
        x = xStart;
        y = yStart;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                is[i][j] = false;
            }
        }
        while (true) {
            char[][] grid = new char[n][n];
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
                for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                    grid[i][j] = maze[i][j];
                }
            }
            int lol[] = BFS(grid, x, y);
            if (lol[0] == -1) {
                break;
            }
            y = lol[2];
            x = lol[1];
            tot += lol[0];
        }
        System.out.println(candy + " " + tot);
    }
}

public static int[] BFS(char[][] maze, int xStart, int yStart) {
    Queue<int[]> queue = new LinkedList<int[]>();
    int start[] = {xStart, yStart, 0, 0};
    queue.add(start);
    while (queue.peek() != null) {
        int[] array = queue.poll();
        int x = array[0];
        int y = array[1];
        if (x < 0 || y < 0 || y > n - 1 || x > n - 1) {
            continue;
        }
        if (maze[x][y] == '#') {
            continue;
        }
        if (maze[x][y] == '*' && !is[x][y]) {
            is[x][y] = true;
            candy++;
            int sta[] = {array[2], x, y};
            return sta;

        }
        if (maze[x][y] >= 'a' && maze[x][y] <= 'f') {
            if (candy < maze[x][y] - 'a' + 1) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        int[][] points = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {-1, 0}, {0, -1}};
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            int sta[] = {x + points[i][0], y + points[i][1], array[2] + 1};
            queue.add(sta);
        }
        maze[x][y] = '#';
    }
    int sta[] = {-1};
    return sta;
}
}
```

I would like to now figure out how to solve it the dynamic way, the solution I gave only works for some cases but not all.